# Linq to NHibernate .ContainsAny() workaround?

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, linq-to-nhibernate

I've rammed into a huge problem. I got to these two objects:
`IList<Product> products;` and 
`Collection collection;`

Both objects contains and `IList<Tag>` named .Tags.

I'm trying to do the this with Linq To NHibernate:

`products = products.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => collection.Tags.Contains(t)));`

This will give an exception, because Linq To NHibernate don't support this. But how can I accomplish this? I just can't find any smart way to only get the `products` that contains the tags that the specific `collection` has.

Thanks in advance!

Btw, the problem seems very similar to [IQueryable contains any of string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126591/iqueryable-contains-any-of-string-array), but in my scenario I don't want to compare with a string array, but with a collection of poco objects.

[EDIT]
I found out that it throws this exception:
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.`

Alternative ways to resolve the issue is welcome too (HQL etc).

Thanks!
[/EDIT]

Comment: Oh, and I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2

Comment: Alternative way: upgrade to the latest version and the new linq provider. Similar queries work. Hql should be possible with 2.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I ended up with a little boring solution, but it works. If anyone hit the same problem:

```
products = _productRepository.Session()
                             .CreateSQLQuery(
                             @"SELECT {p.*} 
                               FROM Products p 
                               WHERE (SELECT COUNT(TagId) 
                                      FROM ProductTags 
                                      WHERE ProductId = p.Id 
                                      AND TagId IN (SELECT TagId 
                                                    FROM CollectionTags 
                                                    WHERE CollectionId = :collectionId)) > 0 
                               AND (ShopId = :shopId)")
                              .AddEntity("p", typeof(Product))
                              .SetInt32("collectionId", collection.Id)
                              .SetInt32("shopId", collection.Shop.Id)
                              .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                              .List<Product>().AsQueryable();
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the underlying type of `collection.Tags`? It may be that LINQ to NH doesn't like that type, or that it doesn't understand accessing the `Tags` property. Does this work?

```
var tags = collection.Tags.ToList();
products = products.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(t => tags.Contains(t)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried it, but I get the same result - an null exception as soon as I access the products collection. The code compiles, it's first at runtime (when I request the results) it throws the exception.

Comment: A quick update:
I added a foreach loop after your code, and now I get a more interesting exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.